# wordpress how to change original image quality during upload (jpeg)

Tags: wordpress, image, upload, jpeg

I using plugins and trying find it in source code WordPress, but i can only change quality for thumbnails. I need 30-40% quality jpeg images instead 90% (default)

Comment: what have you done so far, where are you facing the problem

Comment: I'm using many plugins, like WP Resized Image Quality and JPG Image Quality ... In the file themes/nameTheme/functions.php adding (add_filter( 'jpeg_quality', create_function( '', 'return 30;' ) );) To change the thumbnail

Answer (score 0):

go to media upload. You can change size of image you upload.

Comment: size does not need to change. And i want configure this process to automatic